# Why do raw types in one place cause generic callsites somewhere else to be treated as raw?

Tags: java, generics, language-design, overloading, raw-types

Consider this example:

```
import java.util.*;

class Foo<T> {
  public int baz(List<String> stringlist) { return 1; }
  public int baz(ArrayList<Object> objectlist) { return 2; }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Foo<String> foo = new Foo<String>(); // (A)
    //Foo foo = new Foo();               // (B)

    System.out.println(foo.baz(new ArrayList<String>()));
  }
}
```

Why does it print `1` in `(A)`, but `2` with `(B)`?

I know how method resolution works, so no need to explain that to me.

I want to know the deeper motivation behind this "feature".
Why is there no erasure warning about it? (There is just one about `Foo foo = new Foo()`.)

Why does method resolution use erased semantics although the generic type is given?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because when the compiler is [resolving overloads](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html), it considers each method as either generic or non-generic, never a mixture of the two, so the candidates are:

1. `Foo<T>.baz(List<String>)`
2. `Foo<T>.baz(ArrayList<Object>)`

if `foo` is a `Foo<String>`, or

1. `Foo.baz(List)`
2. `Foo.baz(ArrayList)`

if `foo` is a `Foo`.

There is no such thing as `Foo.baz(List<String>)`.  Either all type parameters are considered or none are.  (I am not aware of this being explicitly stated in the JLS, but it makes sense since treating a generic method as if it were the raw equivalent is a backwards-compatibility feature.)

In the first case, `Foo<T>.baz(List<String>)` matches but `Foo<T>.baz(ArrayList<Object>)` does not.

In the second case both functions match, and `Foo.baz(ArrayList)` is [more specific](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#301183), so it is chosen.

Answer (score 0):

It won't even compile case (A) if you only keep the single method `baz(ArrayList<Object>)` (error: method cannot be applied to given type).
I guess `ArrayList<String>` is not a subclass of `ArrayList<Object>`.

It's weird that it does compile in case (B), but they must have taken some weird decisions to kept backward compatibility with non-generic collections.

Comment: Sure it isn't. `ArrayList`s element type isn't defined as covariant.